# How to access outlook mailbox using Python

Tags: python, email, automation, outlook, office365

I am doing a project that makes a post request when the mailbox receives an email, the only thing that I need is access to the mailbox. The mail address is from office 365. I have already tried access using Microsoft Graph API, exchange library, and IMAP library but with no success. At the moment, I am doing the project using win32com.client library, but to use I need outlook installed on my machine. The Idea is to access my mailbox from another server. Does anyone know how can I do it? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you getting an error response? What is it? Could you add some code of your try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api). You may find the [Getting Started with Microsoft Graph and Mail API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-gm25wusIQ) video on YouTube helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tried again using https://github.com/O365/python-o365 API and this time I get it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution for others. It makes sense to mark the answer then.